# Sum of string values from dictionary

Tags: python

I have below snippet, Need advice on how to sum/add up values from Dictionary.

```
courses = {'Math':'65','English':'70','History':'80','French':'70','Science':'60'}
```

I have used below command to obtain the results but was unsuccessful.

```
total = sum(courses.values())
```

Comment: Convert the values to `int`

Answer (score 6):

The values in your dict are strings. Just convert them to int before you pass them to sum.

```
>>> courses = {'Math':'65','English':'70','History':'80','French':'70','Science':'60'}
>>> sum(int(x) for x in courses.values())
345
```

or use map

```
>>> sum(map(int, courses.values()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Appreciated!!!